# Broad Crawling with scrapy

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I am trying to build a broad crawler with scrapy, How can run many concurrent spiders but at the same time keeping them from crawling the same domain?

Answer (score 0):

What's the purpose of running multiple spiders with the same domain?
You want to accelerate crawling process or spiders have a different logic?

1. If first, take a look at the [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/broad-crawls.html#increase-concurrency). You should increase `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 100` in your `settings.py` file. One single spider shall suffice.
2. If spiders have a different logic, just create a separete class for each of them.

Comment: Yes i want to run multiple spiders on different domains. I am sorry if the question was unclear. If a set CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 100 and CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 1, will this solve the problem and i will have 100 different spiders each crawling its own domain?

Comment: It will be the same spider, look at the [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests-per-ip) [+](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests)

Answer (score 0):

I think I see where you're coming from. You want distributed throttling per domain so that you can run many crawls in parallel while respecting limits for every single website. To do this you will need to develop a middleware that talks to something (database?) shared among spiders.

One well known such system is [scrapy-cluster](http://scrapy-cluster.readthedocs.io).

As you can see [here](http://scrapy-cluster.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/crawler/controlling.html?highlight=hits%20scale) it supports fine grained distributed control over how "hard" you hit every domain.

It also has a de-dupeing functionality similar to what you're looking for (see [here](http://scrapy-cluster.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/crawler/settings.html#dupe-timeout)). The main difference is that it doesn't de-dupe `Item`s but Requests but this should be even better.

Comment: Yes that is what i am looking to do. I want to 1. Have my scrapers use the same pool of domains, 2. All the spiders return their items to the same  pool of scraped items where they are filtered for duplicates. 3. Make sure that they do not start crawling on the same domain. Does scrap cloud have this features built in by the way? I just saw their website now.

Comment: Updated the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if what you need is a distributed crawler, you could use [Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org) or [StormCrawler](http://stormcrawler.net) instead. Both are designed to run on a distributed cluster, the former using Apache Hadoop and the latter Apache Storm.